Calculate the segment $MQ $in the circle below
In the figure if $RN = 5m$, $MB = 4m$ and $RN \parallel B$.
Calculate MQ
$\angle RMN = 90^o$
(Answer($\frac{4\sqrt{15}}{5}$)

I try:
$x+r = 4 \implies x= 4-r(1)$\
$AM=AB-BM =2r-4(2)$
$\theta = \frac{\alpha}{2} + \frac{\beta}{2}(3)$\
$ARcos \theta+BN cos \theta+BN = AB (4)$
$AR=AN \implies ARNB_{(trap.isos.)}$
Let $NH$ be the height of the trapezium
T.Pyt: $NH=\sqrt{r^2-\frac{25}{4}}$


$ MR^2+MN^2=AM^2+BM^2=$
$(2r-4)^2+ 4^2=4r^2-16r+16+16$
$\therefore MR^2 +MN^2=4r^2-16r+32(I)$
$\triangle MRN: 5^2=MR^2+MN^2=25(II)$
$De(I): 4r^2-16r+32=25 \implies 4r^2-16r+7=0$
$\therefore r=\frac{1}{2} \vee r=\frac{7}{2} \implies 2r=7$
$AM=2.\frac{7}{2}-4=3$
$AG=GH=\frac{7-5}{2}=1 \implies GM=3-1=2$
$MH=4-1=3$
$\triangle MHN: h^2=MN^2-3^2=MN^2-9$
$\triangle RGM: h^2=MR^2-2^2=MR^2-4$
$\therefore MN^2-MR^2=5(III)$
From:$(II): 2MR^2=30 \implies MN^2=15 \therefore MN = \sqrt{15}$
$MQ.MN=AM.BM \implies MQ.MN=3.4=12$
$\therefore MQ=\frac{12}{\sqrt{15}}=\frac{12\sqrt15}{15}=\boxed{\frac{4\sqrt{15}}{5}}$



can you use Marlen's theorem for an isosceles trapezoid?

My mistake, It is not Marlen's theorem, but the theorem of lines parallel to the diameter

never heard of that theorem

@hellofriends The deduction is very simple and comes directly from Marlen's theorem. I posted it now with the answer to the deduction


The triangles $\triangle MOH_3$ and $\triangle OH_3 N$ have the same side length $OH_3$:
$$
r^2 - (x + a)^2 = (\Omega_2 - r)^2 - a^2 \tag{1}
$$
From the Pythagorean theorem in $\triangle MNH_2$:
$$
r^2 - \left(\frac{\Omega_1}{2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\Omega_1}{2} + \Omega_2 - r\right)^2 = (x + 2a)^2 \tag{2}
$$
Using the Euclidean theorem in triangle $\triangle RMN$:
$$
r^2 - \left(\frac{\Omega_1}{2}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{\Omega_1}{2} - \Omega_2 + r\right) \left(\frac{\Omega_1}{2} + \Omega_2 - r\right) \tag{3}
$$
Solving (1), (2), and (3) we get:
$$
x = \frac{ \sqrt{ -\Omega_2 (\Omega_1 - \Omega_2) \left( \sqrt{ \Omega_1^2 - \Omega_2^2 } - \Omega_1 - \Omega_2 \right) } }{ \sqrt{\Omega_1} } \stackrel{\Omega_1=5\operatorname{m};\Omega_2=4 \operatorname{m}}{=} \boxed{ 4 \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}} \operatorname{m}}.
$$
To check it,
FullSimplify[Solve[{r^2 - (x + a)^2 == (\omega2 - r)^2 - a^2, r^2 - (omega1/2)^2 == (omega1/2 - omega2 + r) (omega1/2 + omega2 - r), r^2 - (omega1/2)^2 + (omega1/2 + omega2 - r)^2 == (x + 2 a)^2}, {r, x, a}]]
$$
\left\{
r \to \frac{1}{2} \left( \Omega_2 - \sqrt{ (\Omega_1 - \Omega_2)(\Omega_1 + \Omega_2) } \right),
x \to \frac{ \sqrt{ -\Omega_2 (\Omega_1 - \Omega_2) \left( \sqrt{ \Omega_1^2 - \Omega_2^2 } - \Omega_1 - \Omega_2 \right) } }{ \sqrt{\Omega_1} },
a \to -\frac{ \sqrt{ -\Omega_2 (\Omega_1 - \Omega_2) \left( \sqrt{ \Omega_1^2 - \Omega_2^2 } - \Omega_1 - \Omega_2 \right) } \left( \Omega_1 \left( \sqrt{ \Omega_1^2 - \Omega_2^2 } + \Omega_2 \right) + \Omega_1^2 - 2 \Omega_2^2 \right) }{ 4 \sqrt{\Omega_1} \Omega_2 (\Omega_1 - \Omega_2) }
\right\}
$$
